# How to produce such results using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, transactions

I edited my question as it seems like people misunderstood what I wanted.

I have a table which has the following columns:

1. Company
2. Transaction ID
3. Transaction Date

The result I want is:

```
|      COMPANY        |  Transaction ID  |Transaction Date  |     GROUP
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|----------
|     Company A       |      t_0001      |    01-01-2014    |         1
|     Company A       |      t_0002      |    02-01-2014    |         1
|     Company A       |      t_0003      |    04-01-2014    |         1
|     Company A       |      t_0003      |    10-01-2014    |         2
|     Company B       |      t_0004      |    02-01-2014    |         1
|     Company B       |      t_0005      |    02-01-2014    |         1
|     Company C       |      t_0006      |    03-01-2014    |         1
|     Company C       |      t_0007      |    05-01-2014    |         2
```

where the transactions and dates are firstly group into companies. The transactions within the company are sorted from the earliest to the latest. The transactions are checked, row by row, if the previous transaction was performed less than 3 days ago in a moving window period.

For example, t_0002 and t_0001 are less than 3 days apart so they fall under group 1. t_0003 and t_0002 are less than 3 days apart so they fall under group 1 even though t_0003 and t_0003 are >= 3 days apart.

I figured the way to go about doing this is to group the data by companies first, following by sorting the transactions by the dates, but I got stuck after this. Like what methods are there I could use to produce this results? Any help on this?

P.S. I am using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: *the transactions are considered to be in the same group if the difference in dates is less than 3 days*. Your groups are ill defined ! What if there is a transaction every day ?

Comment: That sounds quite a lot like _gaps and islands_ problem. You'll find a lot of example by searching with it.

Comment: No answers for this?

Comment: How does t_0001 end up in *any* group? It has no previous transaction. t_0004 wouldn't have a previous transaction either in the context of Company B's transactions.

Answer (score 0):

I have determined days difference between each company following by transaction id. so if days difference is less than 3 goes to group 1 other are 2. Based on your requirement alter the lag clause and use it.

```
   select *,isnull(
   case when datediff(day,
    lag([Transaction Date]) over(partition by company order by [transaction id]),[Transaction Date])>=2
    then
    2
    end ,1)group1 
     from #Table1
```

Comment: there are potentially unlimited number of groups so this wont work

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the numbering in groups, use

```
select *, 
dense_rank() over(partition by company order by transaction_date) -
(select count(distinct transaction_date) from t 
 where t1.company=company  
 and datediff(dd,transaction_date,t1.transaction_date) between 1 and 2) grp
from t t1
order by 1,3
```

**[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/SVUE71114)**

If continuous numbers are needed for groups, use

```
select company,transaction_id,transaction_date,
dense_rank() over(partition by company order by grp) grp 
from (select *, dense_rank() over(partition by company order by transaction_date) -
      (select count(distinct transaction_date) from t
       where t1.company=company 
       and datediff(dd,transaction_date,t1.transaction_date) between 1 and 2) grp
       from t t1
       ) x
order by 1,3
```

Comment: @Winston .. the query gives you the exact results as explained. what makes you think this isn't what you need?

Comment: try using this dataset: http://rextester.com/SVUE71114 . The first three rows are supposed to be in the same group because t002 is less than 3 days apart from t001 and also because t003 is less than 3 days apart from t002. Basically it always compare with the previous 1 transaction date and not all the previous ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table xn (
  [Company] char(1),
  [Transaction ID] char(6),
  [Transaction Date] date,
  primary key ([Company], [Transaction ID], [Transaction Date])
);

insert into xn values
('A', 't_0001', '2014-01-01'),
('A', 't_0002', '2014-01-02'),
('A', 't_0003', '2014-01-04'),
('A', 't_0003', '2014-01-10'),
('B', 't_0004', '2014-01-02'),
('B', 't_0005', '2014-01-02'),
('C', 't_0006', '2014-01-03'),
('C', 't_0007', '2014-01-05');
```

Each query builds on the one before. There are more concise ways to write queries like this, but I think this way helps when you're learning window functions like `lag(...) over (...)`.

The first one here brings the previous transaction date into the "current" row.

```
select 
    [Company], 
    [Transaction ID], 
    [Transaction Date], 
    lag ([Transaction Date]) over (partition by [Company] order by [Transaction Date]) as [Prev Transaction Date]
from xn
```

This query determines the number of days between the "current" transaction date and the previous transaction date.

```
select 
    [Company], 
    [Transaction ID], 
    [Transaction Date], 
    [Prev Transaction Date], 
    DateDiff(d, [Prev Transaction Date], [Transaction Date]) as [Days Between]
from (select 
          [Company], 
          [Transaction ID], 
          [Transaction Date], 
          lag ([Transaction Date]) over (partition by [Company] order by [Transaction Date]) as [Prev Transaction Date]
      from xn) x
```

This does the grouping based on the number of days.

```
select 
    [Company],
    [Transaction ID], 
    [Transaction Date], 
    case when [Days Between] between 0 and 3 then 1
         when [Days Between] is null then 1
         when [Days Between] > 3 then 2
         else 'Ummm'
    end as [Group Num]
from (
        select 
            [Company], 
            [Transaction ID], 
            [Transaction Date], 
            [Prev Transaction Date], 
            DateDiff(d, [Prev Transaction Date], [Transaction Date]) as [Days Between]
        from (select 
                  [Company], 
                  [Transaction ID], 
                  [Transaction Date], 
                  lag ([Transaction Date]) over (partition by [Company] order by [Transaction Date]) as [Prev Transaction Date]
              from xn) x  
) y;
```